# Frequency of "A and B" for each specific character of other column

Tags: command-line, text-formatting

I wanted to know the frequency of A and B in column $3 and $4 for each different character present in column $1.
Command line in linux.

**Example** my input:

```
ID01 a1 A B
ID01 a2 A B
ID01 a3 A B
ID02 a1 B B
ID02 a2 B B
ID02 a3 B B
OA03 a1 A A
OA03 a2 A A
OA03 a3 A A
EA04 a1 -- --
EA04 a2 -- --
EA04 a3 -- --
```

I want this **output**:

```
ID01 A 0.50
ID01 B 0.50
ID02 A 0.00
ID02 B 1.00
OA03 A 1.00
OA03 B 0.00
EA04 A 0.00
EA04 B 0.00
```

How I can do this?
Thank you!

Comment: `awk '{h[$1]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }' input > output` I tried to adapt it to my problem, but I could not. I thought I'd create separate files, but the actual number of different characters in column 1 is 54000, so big. I tried other command line, but similar of this, that no specify two column.

Comment: Based on the output, it sounds like you want the **percentage** (0.50 == 50% 1.00 == 100%) of frequency, which requires knowing the max number of columns rather then just the frequency of each character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to adapt your associative array based awk solution would be to concatenate the contents of `$3` and `$4` for each `$1`, and then at the `END` make use of the fact that `gsub` returns the number of replacements to count occurrences of `A` and `B` in the respective *strings*. For example:

```
awk '{
  a[$1]=a[$1]$3$4; 
  next;
} 
END{
  for (i in a) {
  n = length(a[i]) == 0 ? 1 : length(a[i]); # avoid div-by-zero
  printf "%s A %.1f\n", i, gsub(/A/,"",a[i])/n; 
  printf "%s B %.1f\n", i, gsub(/B/,"",a[i])/n;}
}' input
EA04 A 0.0
EA04 B 0.0
OA03 A 1.0
OA03 B 0.0
ID01 A 0.5
ID01 B 0.5
ID02 A 0.0
ID02 B 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver, but I do not understand this part: `n = length(a[i]) == 0 ? 1 : length(a[i]); # avoid div-by-zero`. How I can defined the length(a[i])? I need to put the number of different character present in column $1? Because apear the following error: `awk: line 2: function lengeth never defined`. What I could do?

Comment: @AmandaBotelhoAlvarenga did you make a typo? it's `length` not `lengeth`. Or perhaps the implementation of awk that you are using does not have a built-in `length` function (I only tested with `awk` and `mawk`)?